# What is a REST way to "publish" an offer?

Tags: rest

I have a rest interface where buy and sell offers are made.
An offer is first created, then potentially edited and finally, published.

Now for my question. Since additional verbs are prohibited in rest, how can I describe publishing of an offer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a potential restful workflow

**Create**

- POST /offers/buys/unpublished { your buy offer resource }

**Edit**

- PUT /offers/buys/unpublished/123 { your complete replacement buy offer resource }
  or
- PATCH /offers/buys/unpublished/123 { a patch document for the fields being edited }

**Publish**

- POST /offers/buys/published { your unpublished resource with ID 123 }

**Delete**

You could delete the offer before or after it was published. In that case you'd have one of these.

- DELETE /offers/buys/unpublished/123
- DELETE /offers/buys/published/123

The paths can be a bit debatable, but generally nouns are acceptable.

I prefer paths like the above (that also have adjectives), but you could do something like `/published-buy-offers` or you could do away with the adjectives and assume the resource's representation has fields to represent the kinds and states of offers. Then the path can be something simple like `/offers`.

Answer (score 0):

> Since additional verbs are prohibited in rest, how can I describe publishing of an offer?

How would you do it with a web site?

You would probably start with a web page, that has a bunch of information about the offer itself.  That page might include links to other web pages that could be useful.

But the key element of the web page would be a form; and that form would include a bunch of fields, some exposed via the user interface because they are intended to be reviewed and edited, others hidden from view.  The form would be submitted by clicking a button, the event handler of which would read the form (the controls, and the meta data), and use that information, along with standardized processing rules, to produce an HTTP request to send to the server.

In other words, pretty much the same thing as what happened when you posted your question on stackoverflow, and when I posted this answer.

The trick of a REST-API is the same idea, but in machine readable form.  In other words, how do we design the web page so that it can be understood without a human being there to resolve the ambiguities?

This means, in turn, that we need to invest more in standardizing our representations and our link relations, so that a machine can learn to recognize the fields in it, and do the right thing.

---

Using a remote authoring idiom is also viable (though less common on the web).  The initial mechanics are basically the same: you follow link relations to find some document that you need.

You edit your local copy of that document, and then request that the server modify its local copy of the document to match yours.

---

In either case, what we are doing is using a general purpose [document transfer protocol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) to move information around.

It's very much the way we used to work with paper in offices: you pull a file out of the file cabinet, you put some new information in the file, you put the file back in the cabinet.  The actual documents encode whatever information you need, but the files, and the labels for the files, and the file cabinets are all general purpose.

On the web, rather than moving pieces of paper, we copy bits over the network.  But the basic idiom is unchanged.

---

> I have a rest interface where buy and sell offers are made.
> An offer is first created, then potentially edited and finally, published.

> how can I describe publishing of an offer?

One of two ways: you define a protocol that can be used to discover some *form* , complete the information in that form and then POST it back to the web server; or you define a protocol that can be used to discover some document, and then PUT/PATCH edits to that document back to the web server.

The "resources" of your API are the documents that are used to navigate these protocols.